# Group by with a substr that is part of a clob

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, clob

I need your help with the following sql:

```
SELECT 
  substr(nd.nne_def,4,3) as bzn
FROM 
    core_def.nne_def nd
group by substr(nd.nne_def,4,4);
```

I got the error:

```
ORA-00932: 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"
```

I need the sql just for analysis not for production code.

How can I group by a substring that is part of a CLOB?

Thx for your help.

Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUBSTR` doesn't work with CLOBs - you need `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT 
  dbms_lob.substr(nd.nne_def,4,4) as bzn
FROM 
  core_def.nne_def nd
group by dbms_lob.substr(nd.nne_def,4,4);
```